# Printing problem with encrypting program in python

Tags: python

I have a problem with my python encrypting program. So I need to transform the numbers from the input message, in this example 3 and 29, 3 should be converted to \4 and 29 to \3\10 (add a \ behind them, add 1 to them and if it is more than one digit it should separate them). It works but it applies these conditions to the converted vowels, so it replaces 'i' with the number 2, and it should be printed as 2, but it applies these previous condition to it and it prints as \3.

Also I can't use functions,RegEx and libraries

```
message = "Did I send 3 or 29 messages?"

message = message.replace('and', '&').replace('or', '|')

vowels = {'a': '0', 'e': '1', 'i': '2', 'o': '3', 'u': '4'}
for vowel, digit in vowels.items():
    message = message.replace(vowel, digit)

encrypted_message = ''
for char in message:
    if char.isalpha():
        encrypted_char = chr(ord(char) - 2)
        encrypted_message += encrypted_char
    elif char.isdigit():
        encrypted_char = '\\' + str(int(char) + 1)
        encrypted_message += encrypted_char
    elif char.isspace():
        space_index = len(encrypted_message.replace(' ', '')) % 3
        replacements = {'0': '#', '1': '$', '2': '%'}
        encrypted_char = replacements[str(space_index)]
        encrypted_message += encrypted_char
    else:
        encrypted_message += char

encrypted_message = encrypted_message[::-1]

print(encrypted_message)
```

This program prints out:

```
?q2\e1\qq2\k%01\3\%|#4\#bl2\q#G$b3\B
```

But instead it should be:

```
?q1e0qq1k%01\3\$|#4\%bl1q$G#b2B
```

Also tried using ChatGPT, but as always it didn't help...

Comment: Do the number replacement before you replace the vowels.

Answer (score 0):

I think life is easier if you seperate your encrypted message from the original message and dont change the original message. Take a look how I work on a list instead of the string, this makes insertion of multiple strings at once more comfortable.

```
message = "Did I send 3 or 29 messages?"

message = message.replace('and', '&').replace('or', '|')

vowels = {'a': '0', 'e': '1', 'i': '2', 'o': '3', 'u': '4'}

result = ["X"] * len(message)  # dummy result list that will be mutated
space_index = 0
space_replacements = {0: '#', 1: '$', 2: '%'}

for idx, char in enumerate(message):
    if char in vowels:
        # replace vowls
        result[idx] = vowels[char]
    elif char.isdigit():
        # replace digits
        result[idx] = result[idx] = "".join(reversed("\\" + str(int(char)+1)))
    elif char.isalpha():
        # replace alpha
        result[idx] = chr(ord(char) -2)
    elif char.isspace():
        # replace spaces
        encrypted_char = space_replacements[space_index % 3]
        result[idx] = encrypted_char
        space_index += 1
    else:
        result[idx] = message[idx]

# flatten result and convert to string
encrypted_message = "".join(reversed(result))
print(encrypted_message)
```

result is

```
# -->  ?q1e0qq1k%01\3\$|#4\%bl1q$G#b2B
```